# How to get default value in a function defined if return is none?

Tags: python

I am fetching the email from the text. But if email is not present in the text then it should return 'absent' word. With this code it is returning an empty list if email is not present.

```
match = re.compile(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+')

def extract_emails(text_ext_doc):

    x = re.findall(match, text_ext_doc) 
    return "absent" if x is None else x
```

Comment: try `return "absent" if not x else x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no match, `findall` will return an empty list, so you can use either "or" operator:

```
def extract_emails(text_ext_doc):
    x = re.findall(match, text_ext_doc)
    return x or 'absent'
```

or "conditional expression":

```
def extract_emails(text_ext_doc):
    x = re.findall(match, text_ext_doc)
    return x if x else 'absent'
```